# Taxonomy Archive URL + Template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, slug

Working on an WP build with custom post types & taxonomies

**Taxonomy** = Reviews
**Example term**s = nes, snes, gamecube

I've got a taxonomy archive page, taxonomy-reviews.php

Going to the url **/reviews/nes** works, but parent **/reviews/** doesn't?

For the parent **/reviews/** am hoping it'll show posts from any of the terms, but it jus 404s for me

Any idea on how to get it to work and what template to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and share the code of your custom post type as you wrote it on your functions.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code of your Custom Post Type it's kind of difficult to answer. I have few hypotheses :

1. Have you **flushed the permalinks** ? You have to go to Settings > Permalinks > and click on **Save** to do so. Repeat this action anytime you modify the rewrite rules of your Custom Post Type.
2. Is the Taxonomy slug the **same** than the Custom Post Type slug ? If so, I guess this is why you have a 404 error page.
3. In your Custom Post Type and in you Taxonomy Post Type, if you want a specific url (and not the default one) as a slug, you can use this argument (please [this documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) for more details) :

   'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'you-slu' ), // you can replace you-slug by your custom slug
4. Please make this change, save your functions.php file and flush your Permalinks (step 1) right after it.
5. The template for displaying your taxonomy page will be **taxonomy-[slug].php** (you have to replace slug by the slug of your taxonomy).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies do not by default have their own archive page, only the taxonomy's terms. You can test this by going to `/category/` on a clean WordPress install: you'll get a 404 for the built-in *Category* taxonomy, but `/category/uncategorized/` will show posts in the *Uncategorized* cateogry.

Specifically what's happening, is that WordPress identifies `category` as a request for a page, so it looks for a page with that slug.

You can create an index page for your custom taxonomy, but it's not a native part of WordPress.